# Why does energy not have gravity?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity

particle with high energy without having mass  travelling through space-time coordinates keeps it energy constant without converting it into mass not curves the graph of spacetime it mean that these particle not possess gravity,But when it converts it's energy into mass it posses gravity. Then why particle with  energy not possess gravity as like particle with mass?

Comment: As it stands, it is unclear what you are trying to ask. Please edit to clarify

Comment: In general relativity energy does distort space-time.

Comment: I think there is an interesting question, but it needs to be asked more clearly - so I vote to close, but Bhagwat do repost if you can make your question clearer and explain more about what you are asking.

Answer (score 4):

First we need to clarify:

1. photons do not have rest mass
2. photons do have energy, and comes from their frequency E=h*f
3. photons do have gravity effects, since they have energy, and the source of gravity is stress-energy
4. when a photon travels next to the sun, both the sun bends spacetime and the photon bends spacetime too, they both react on each other

Comment: In modern terminology, mass = rest mass, so energy does not imply mass for photons. Please don't help spreading the old-fashioned "relativistic mass" concept, it has caused so much confusion in the past. Point 3 is correct, but not because of mass, but because the source of gravity is stress-energy.

Comment: OK I will edit my answer

Comment: Okay but when photon is stationary then it bend space time, is it?

Comment: @BhagwatDeshmukh photons are never stationary.

Comment: Dear Bhagwat Deshmukh, photons are always travelling at speed c when measured locally. There is no reference frame in which they would be at rest. You are thinking of this in a way where everything needs to speed up. But that is not true. Everything was created as energy, photons, and that is the speed that particles with no rest mass travel at. Particles without rest mass do not travel in the time dimension, their speed is zero. Everything is relative to that, and you need to slow down in space to start moving in the time dimension.

Comment: That is why particles with mass, and everything that we know as bigger objects move in the time dimension, that is why we can see time flow.

Comment: The only way to slow down a photon is to absorb it.

Answer (score 0):

As it is not really clear what you are asking it might be of help if you have a look at the stress-energy-tensor https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor whose 16 components contribute as sources to gravity. Note that energy being not invariant is no component of the SET but energy density is.